# Django celery monitor doesn't show any tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I cannot see the tasks in admin.
I followed the steps in https://github.com/jezdez/django-celery-monitor

I used

```
celery==4.1.1
django-celery-results==1.0.1
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django_celery_monitor==1.1.2
```

ran `manage.py migrate celery_monitor` The migrations went well. ran `celery -A lbb events -l info --camera django_celery_monitor.camera.Camera --frequency=2.0` and `celery -A lbb worker -l info` in separate shells. But still cannot see the tasks I ran in `celery-monitor > tasks` table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running celery command with -E to force event worked for me.

`celery -A proj worker -l info -E`